# Como hacer Split con un carácter que sea imposible que ingrese el usuario

Tags: java, json, string, split

Estoy usando un código java con `jsonSchema` y la única forma que tengo para diferenciar las validaciones es con un `split` de `'/'` para poder diferenciar en que profundidad está del *json* y así extraer el valor.

El problema reside en que si alguien escribe una fecha `"30/02/2019"` entonces soy incapaz de saber en a que profundidad está para saber que campo estoy sacando.

¿Alguna idea para crear un carácter que sea imposible de ingresar por un usuario u otra alternativa?.

```
String[] cadenaType = type.split("/"); 
String valor = "";

    if (cadenaType.length >= 2) {
        valor = cadenaType[cadenaType.length-2];
    } else {
        valor = cadenaType[cadenaType.length-1];
    }
```

Comment: ¿Nos puedes mostrar el JSON?

Comment: Os puedo mostrar un ejemplo,¿Te vale?

Comment: Sí, añádelo en la pregunta!

Comment: ¿Qué significa "a que profundidad"?

Comment: @Juan se refiere a que antes empleaba '/' para dividir su cadena, pero las fechas venían en formato 'dd/mm/yy' asi que tenia que identificar si la subcadena era día, mes o año según su posición (a eso le llama profundidad).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Un carácter que un usuario no podría escribir podría ser por ejemplo el carácter nulo el cual tiene como codigo ascii el 0.

En el siguiente ejemplo puedes ver como funciona:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      char c=(char)0;     //este es el caracter especial para hacer el split
      System.out.println("el caracter 0 se ve como: \""+c+"\"");  
      String type = "29/02/2019"+c+"30/02/2019"+c+"31/02/2019"+c+"28/02/2019";
      String[] cadenaType = type.split(c+"");
      System.out.println("Se ha dividido la cadena en:");
      for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
        System.out.println(cadenaType[i]);  
    }
}
```

El resultado será:

```
el caracter 0 se ve como: " "
Se ha dividido la cadena en:
29/02/2019
30/02/2019
31/02/2019
28/02/2019
```

Puedes ver la demostración del código en el siguiente enlace:

<kbd>[Demostración en JDOODLE](https://www.jdoodle.com/a/1yMv)</kbd>

Espero sea lo que buscas, saludos.

Comment: Como aclaración, y algo que he ido a probar al JDOODLE, es que `(char)0 != ' '`, aun que visualmente sean iguales. Muy buena respuesta, me la guardo :)

Comment: así es @x3k_js se ve como un espacio pero no lo es, saludos.

Comment: @x3k_js El caracter ' ' (espacio) es el decimal 32 o 0x20